# Change incoming sip uri from AsteriskNow to e.164 format

Tags: asterisk, lync-2013, ucma

I write an IVR using UCMA, When I want to transfer the call I've got runtime error.
after searching I found that the problem is the uri of call from asterisk wich is in form of 1234 instead of +1234. How and where can i set incomming call uri in form of e.164? In lync setting? or in AsteriskNow.
I am using lync 2013, UCMA 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change callerid on outbound call by using something like that

exten => _x.,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=+${CALLERID(num)})

For asterisknow it maybe more complex, it is not doable via web so need see your configs.

After that call will come as +1234.

Comment: I wrote the rule:
exten => _x.,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=+${CALLERID(num)})

But in  lync side( in my ucma app) I'm getting __"sip:+1234@my.domain"__ instead of __"tel:+1234 phone-context=enterprise"__

Comment: Not think you can change correct behavour(as described in rfc) by incorrect lync-style. You can try change source code and recompile with your variant.